# Solidity method taking in bytes32 and hashing but values with previous hash don't match

Tags: hash, solidity

Here's the code:

```
function playGame(bytes32 hashedMove) public returns (bool) {
        require(
            playerOne != address(0x0) && playerTwo != address(0x0),
            "Game needs more players to join first"
        );
        require(
            msg.sender == playerOne || msg.sender == playerTwo,
            "You did not join the game as a player"
        );

        if (msg.sender == playerOne && hashedPlayerOneMove == "") {
            hashedPlayerOneMove = hashedMove;
            emit PlayerMadeMove(playerOne);
        } else if (msg.sender == playerTwo && hashedPlayerTwoMove == "") {
            hashedPlayerTwoMove = hashedMove;
            emit PlayerMadeMove(playerTwo);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The above method takes in a hashedMove argument which I am using the following site to get: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

I send a value of `2test2` hashed which is `0x0698472c4668bddd0c694601ca101551bd7b5cfe6dc780ab37bccfc99ad22e4c`

Now another method takes in the constituents of the hash which are `2` and `test2` to compare it with the stored hash:

```
function revealPlayerChoice(uint256 move, bytes32 password)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(
            hashedPlayerOneMove != bytes32(0x0) &&
                hashedPlayerTwoMove != bytes32(0x0),
            "The game is still running!"
        );

        bytes32 hashedAnswer = getSaltedHash(move, password);

        console.logBytes32(hashedAnswer);
        console.logBytes32(hashedPlayerOneMove);

        if (msg.sender == playerOne && hashedAnswer == hashedPlayerOneMove) {
            playerOneMove = move;
        } else if (
            msg.sender == playerTwo && hashedAnswer == hashedPlayerTwoMove
        ) {
            playerTwoMove = move;
        }

        if (playerOneMove != 0 && playerTwoMove != 0) {
            getGameOutcome();
        }
    }
```

I'm sending 2 as uint and `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007465737432` (`test2` in [bytes](https://onlinestringtools.com/convert-string-to-bytes)) to the `revealPlayerChoice` method. However the values I'm getting from the console log are different. `hashedAnswer` is the hash I'm calculating in the method and `hashedPlayerOneMove` is the hash stored in `playGame` method.

for example, The console log outputs are

```
0x566d7dd4e9dc72e9beef887f2982703a0d0f9dd1b6505ee3ff5310c7383637bd
0x0698472c4668bddd0c694601ca101551bd7b5cfe6dc780ab37bccfc99ad22e4c
```

I would like to understand why the values are different? I'm using keccak256 to hash in solidity (pragma solidity ^0.8.0;) as well:

```
function getSaltedHash(uint answer, bytes32 salt) pure returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(answer, salt));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your problem might be what `abi.encodePacked(answer, salt)` is returning.

When you pass the following arguments:

```
uint256 answer = 2
bytes32 salt = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007465737432
```

`abi.encodePacked(answer, salt)` returns:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007465737432
```

And then, if you run the `keccak256(bytes)` with the previous value, it returns:

```
0x566d7dd4e9dc72e9beef887f2982703a0d0f9dd1b6505ee3ff5310c7383637bd
```

Comment: So how may I achive my desired outcome?

Comment: I tried using `ethers.utils.solidityPacked()` but that gave a different output from `abi.encodedPacked`.

Comment: If you use `ethers.utils.solidityPack(["uint256", "bytes32"],[answer, salt])`, it returns the same as Solidity's `abi.encodePacked(answer, salt)`.